# PySpark exception in cloudpicker

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-compute-engine

I am using spark 2.4.0 in Google Cloud Compute Engine having CentOS 6 and having 3.75 GM Memory.
When I tried to go into pyspark mode, it is throwing the below mentioned error.

```
[user@pb-instance bin]$ pyspark
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-17)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/spark/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkConf
  File "/home/user/spark/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "/home/user/spark/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pyspark import accumulators
  File "/home/user/spark/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/accumulators.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pyspark.serializers import read_int, PickleSerializer
  File "/home/user/spark/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 71, in <module>
    from pyspark import cloudpickle
  File "/home/user/spark/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 246, in <module>
    class CloudPickler(Pickler):
  File "/home/user/spark/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 270, in CloudPickler
    dispatch[memoryview] = save_memoryview
NameError: name 'memoryview' is not defined
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memoryview type is new in Python 2.7, as you are using Python 2.6.6 the type is not defined.

I set up a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance with the same configuration and I got the same error.

In the `./bash_profile` file I had the following line:

`export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python`

So if I run python in the command line it uses the 2.6.6 version.

Running this command `scl enable python27 bash` changes the default version  to 2.7 and solves the issue:

**EDIT:**

I am going to post the steps to install pyspark from scratch in CentOS 6 Google Compute instance. Follow this steps from your `$HOME` directory.

1. Download spark `curl -O http://apache.rediris.es/spark/spark-2.4.0/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz`
2. Unzip it `tar -xvzf spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz`
3. Install Java 8 JDK `sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk`
4. Add this at the end of .bash_profile:

   `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64/`
   `export SPARK_HOME=$HOME/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7`
   `export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH`
   `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python`

   Note: You can check your `JAVA_HOME` path with `alternatives --config java`
5. Run `scl enable python27 bash`

With this command python27 will be default version until you logout. If you want it to persist add the command to .bash_profile too.

Comment: Hi llompalles, can you please paste your whole bash_profile file?

Comment: @ParijatBose, I updated the answer with all the steps to run pyspark.

Comment: @ParijatBose, Could you accept my answer if it solved your issue? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cent-OS uses python 2.6 as default, so install a separate python2.7 anywhere in the system and then simply set the environment variable:

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

add the command to ~/.bash_profile to make it permanent.